# A matrix with zero rows and 1000 columns?

Tags: c++, opencv

I was looking at an example of the `CvNormalBayesClassifier::train` in which the input/output matrix is to be a 1D vector.

The example I was looking at achieved this by creating a cv::Mat matrix with 0 rows and 1000 columns using this line:

`Mat trainingData(0, 1000, CV_32FC1);`

Reading the basic data types in opencv documentation this is what I found for Mat:

> There are many different ways to create Mat object. Here are the some
>   popular ones:
>
> ```
> using create(nrows, ncols, type) method or
>
>     the similar constructor
>
> Mat(nrows, ncols, type[, fill_value]) constructor.
> ```

In any way the first parameter is the rows. The way I look at it is even if we do create a 1000 column matrix it will atleast have 1 row. How can it have 0 rows?

Sorry if this is a very basic question.

update: upon request, here is the complete code.

```
    #include <vector>
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace boost::filesystem;
using namespace cv;

//location of the training data
#define TRAINING_DATA_DIR "data/train/"
//location of the evaluation data
#define EVAL_DATA_DIR "data/eval/"

//See article on BoW model for details
Ptr<DescriptorMatcher> matcher = DescriptorMatcher::create("FlannBased");
Ptr<DescriptorExtractor> extractor = DescriptorExtractor::create("SURF");
Ptr<FeatureDetector> detector = FeatureDetector::create("SURF");

//See article on BoW model for details
int dictionarySize = 1000;
TermCriteria tc(CV_TERMCRIT_ITER, 10, 0.001);
int retries = 1;
int flags = KMEANS_PP_CENTERS;

//See article on BoW model for details
BOWKMeansTrainer bowTrainer(dictionarySize, tc, retries, flags);
//See article on BoW model for details
BOWImgDescriptorExtractor bowDE(extractor, matcher);

/**
 * \brief Recursively traverses a folder hierarchy. Extracts features from the training images and adds them to the bowTrainer.
 */
void extractTrainingVocabulary(const path& basepath) {
    for (directory_iterator iter = directory_iterator(basepath); iter
            != directory_iterator(); iter++) {
        directory_entry entry = *iter;

    if (is_directory(entry.path())) {

        cout << "Processing directory " << entry.path().string() << endl;
        extractTrainingVocabulary(entry.path());

    } else {

        path entryPath = entry.path();
        if (entryPath.extension() == ".jpg") {

            cout << "Processing file " << entryPath.string() << endl;
            Mat img = imread(entryPath.string());
            if (!img.empty()) {
                vector<KeyPoint> keypoints;
                detector->detect(img, keypoints);
                if (keypoints.empty()) {
                    cerr << "Warning: Could not find key points in image: "
                            << entryPath.string() << endl;
                } else {
                    Mat features;
                    extractor->compute(img, keypoints, features);
                    bowTrainer.add(features);
                }
            } else {
                cerr << "Warning: Could not read image: "
                        << entryPath.string() << endl;
            }

        }
    }
}
}

/**
 * \brief Recursively traverses a folder hierarchy. Creates a BoW descriptor for each image encountered.
 */
void extractBOWDescriptor(const path& basepath, Mat& descriptors, Mat& labels) {
    for (directory_iterator iter = directory_iterator(basepath); iter
            != directory_iterator(); iter++) {
        directory_entry entry = *iter;
        if (is_directory(entry.path())) {
            cout << "Processing directory " << entry.path().string() << endl;
            extractBOWDescriptor(entry.path(), descriptors, labels);
        } else {
            path entryPath = entry.path();
            if (entryPath.extension() == ".jpg") {
                cout << "Processing file " << entryPath.string() << endl;
                Mat img = imread(entryPath.string());
                if (!img.empty()) {
                    vector<KeyPoint> keypoints;
                    detector->detect(img, keypoints);
                    if (keypoints.empty()) {
                        cerr << "Warning: Could not find key points in image: "
                                << entryPath.string() << endl;
                    } else {
                        Mat bowDescriptor;
                        bowDE.compute(img, keypoints, bowDescriptor);
                        descriptors.push_back(bowDescriptor);
                        float label=atof(entryPath.filename().c_str());
                        labels.push_back(label);
                    }
                } else {
                    cerr << "Warning: Could not read image: "
                            << entryPath.string() << endl;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {

cout<<"Creating dictionary..."<<endl;
extractTrainingVocabulary(path(TRAINING_DATA_DIR));
vector<Mat> descriptors = bowTrainer.getDescriptors(); //descriptors from training images
int count=0;
for(vector<Mat>::iterator iter=descriptors.begin();iter!=descriptors.end();iter++)
{
    count+=iter->rows;
}
cout<<"Clustering "<<count<<" features"<<endl;
Mat dictionary = bowTrainer.cluster();
bowDE.setVocabulary(dictionary);
cout<<"Processing training data..."<<endl;
Mat trainingData(0, dictionarySize, CV_32FC1);
Mat labels(0, 1, CV_32FC1);
extractBOWDescriptor(path(TRAINING_DATA_DIR), trainingData, labels);

NormalBayesClassifier classifier;
cout<<"Training classifier..."<<endl;

classifier.train(trainingData, labels);

cout<<"Processing evaluation data..."<<endl;
Mat evalData(0, dictionarySize, CV_32FC1);
Mat groundTruth(0, 1, CV_32FC1);
extractBOWDescriptor(path(EVAL_DATA_DIR), evalData, groundTruth);

cout<<"Evaluating classifier..."<<endl;
Mat results;
classifier.predict(evalData, &results);

double errorRate = (double) countNonZero(groundTruth - results) / evalData.rows;
        ;
cout << "Error rate: " << errorRate << endl;

}
```

Comment: A 1D vector has 1 row and N columns (or vice versa).

Comment: A matrix with 0 rows is like the sound of one hand clapping. Very zen, but not very useful. To put any data into it, you'd need at least one row.

Comment: Probably the matrix is extended somewhere after that, e.g. by a resize operation or may be it is automatically resized upon filling with data. Show us more code.

Comment: Could you post a link to your example?

Comment: code added, thank you for your responses so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It makes sense now that you've posted the code.  This 0-row vector is initialized to have 0 rows, but it is created incrementally.

The 0-row matrix gets passed to `extractBOWDescriptor()`, which itself computes several descriptors and uses `cv::Mat.push_back()` to add rows to the matrix.

It begins with 0 rows because at the start we have no descriptors to populate the matrix.

Comment: Thank you, this makes more sense now. I was confused as I thought push_back could only be used with vectors. I now know that they can be used to add elements below the last line of a matrix.

Comment: Also @Chris can you please explain one more confusion I have regarding the code. Instead of making a new topic for it it would be great if I can get it sorted out here. I have no idea what is going on in this line: ``float label=atof(entryPath.filename().c_str()); labels.push_back(label);`` I know atof converts string to double but isnt the code converting the file name to double? how is that helping?  Thank you

Comment: It is likely specific to the data being read in, but yes, it has some filename, which it then converts to a float.  My guess is that the files are sequentially labeled by numbers, and that's why it's being represented in that manner.  They might also be named by their label (class) so you have the ground truth during classification.  Sorry, I can't be sure since I don't know what the data is :)

Comment: Thank you for your helpful responses.