# OpenCV 3.0 Normal Bayes Classifier error

Tags: c++, opencv3.0

I am trying to create a classifier for a bag of words. I found a question on this website ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13664437/a-matrix-with-zero-rows-and-1000-columns)) that helped me put the below code together, but I am stuck at `classifier->train(trainingData,ml::ROW_SAMPLE, labels);`. Essentially, the program runs fine, but when it gets to this line, the program crashes. Apparently, the line is performing a division by zero, and therefore crashing. I have looked through the code and I am not able to find the error. It might be a translation error from openCV 2 -> 3, not really sure. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/features2d/features2d.hpp>
#include <opencv2/xfeatures2d.hpp>
#include <opencv2/ml.hpp>

#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <string.h>




using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

#define TRAINING_DATA_DIR "testImages/"
#define EVAL_DATA_DIR "evalImages/"


int dictSize = 1000;
TermCriteria tc(CV_TERMCRIT_ITER, 10, 0.001);
int retries = 1;
int flags = KMEANS_PP_CENTERS;

Ptr<FeatureDetector> detector = xfeatures2d::SURF::create();
Ptr<DescriptorExtractor> extractor = xfeatures2d::SURF::create();
Ptr<DescriptorMatcher> matcher = FlannBasedMatcher::create("FlannBased");



BOWKMeansTrainer bowTrainer(dictSize, tc, retries, flags);
BOWImgDescriptorExtractor bowDE(extractor, matcher);

void extractTrainingVocabulary(string path){
    struct dirent *de = NULL;
    DIR *d = NULL;
    d = opendir(path.c_str());

    if(d == NULL)
    {
        cerr << "Couldn't open directory" << endl;

    } else {
        // Add all the names of the files to be processed to a vector
        vector<string> files;
        while ((de = readdir(d))) {
            string nameOfFile(de->d_name);
            if ((strcmp(de->d_name,".") != 0) && (strcmp(de->d_name,"..") != 0)  && (strcmp(de->d_name,".DS_Store") != 0)) {
                files.push_back(nameOfFile);
            }
        }

        // Loop through all elements
        for (int f = 0; f < files.size(); f++){
            string fullPath = "./";
            fullPath += TRAINING_DATA_DIR;
            fullPath += files[f];

            cout << "[" << f+1 << "/" << files.size() << "]\tProcessing image: " << fullPath << endl;

            Mat input = imread(fullPath);
            if (!input.empty()){
                // Find all keypoints
                vector<KeyPoint> keypoints;
                detector->detect(input, keypoints);
                if (keypoints.empty()){
                    cerr << "Warning! could not find any keypoints in image " << fullPath << endl;
                } else {
                    // Extract the features
                    Mat features;
                    extractor->compute(input, keypoints, features);
                    // Add them to the trainer
                    bowTrainer.add(features);
                }
            } else {
                cerr << "Could not read image " << fullPath << endl;
            }
        }

    }
}

void extractBOWDescriptor(string path, Mat& descriptors, Mat& labels){
    struct dirent *de = NULL;
    DIR *d = NULL;
    d = opendir(path.c_str());

    if(d == NULL)
    {
        cerr << "Couldn't open directory" << endl;

    } else {
        // Add all the names of the files to be processed to a vector
        vector<string> files;
        while ((de = readdir(d))) {
            string nameOfFile(de->d_name);
            if ((strcmp(de->d_name,".") != 0) && (strcmp(de->d_name,"..") != 0)  && (strcmp(de->d_name,".DS_Store") != 0)) {
                files.push_back(nameOfFile);
            }
        }

        // Loop through all elements
        for (int f = 0; f < files.size(); f++){
            string fullPath = "./";
            fullPath += EVAL_DATA_DIR;
            fullPath += files[f];

            cout << "[" << f+1 << "/" << files.size() << "]\tProcessing image: " << fullPath << endl;

            Mat input = imread(fullPath);
            if (!input.empty()){
                // Find all keypoints
                vector<KeyPoint> keypoints;
                detector->detect(input, keypoints);
                if (keypoints.empty()){
                    cerr << "Warning! could not find any keypoints in image " << fullPath << endl;
                } else {
                    Mat bowDescriptor;
                    bowDE.compute(input, keypoints, bowDescriptor);
                    descriptors.push_back(bowDescriptor);
                    // Current file
                    string fileName = files[f];
                    // Strip extension
                    fileName.erase (fileName.end()-4, fileName.end());

                    float label = atof(fileName.c_str());
                    cout << "Filename: " << fileName << endl;

                    labels.push_back(label);
                }
            } else {
                cerr << "Could not read image " << fullPath << endl;
            }
        }

    }
}




int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    // ============================ LEARN ============================
    cout << "Creating dict" << endl;
    extractTrainingVocabulary(TRAINING_DATA_DIR);




    vector<Mat> descriptors = bowTrainer.getDescriptors();

    int count=0;
    for(vector<Mat>::iterator iter=descriptors.begin();iter!=descriptors.end();iter++){
        count+=iter->rows;
    }

    cout << "Clustering " << count << " features. This might take a while..." << endl;

    Mat dictionary = bowTrainer.cluster();

    cout << "Writing to dict...";
    FileStorage fs("dict.yml",FileStorage::WRITE);
    fs << "vocabulary" << dictionary;
    fs.release();
    cout << "Done!" << endl;

    // =========================== EXTRACT ===========================
    // This will have to be loaded if we run it in two different instances
    bowDE.setVocabulary(dictionary);

    cout << "Processing training data..." << endl;
    Mat trainingData(0, dictSize, CV_32FC1);
    Mat labels(0,1,CV_32FC1);

    extractBOWDescriptor(EVAL_DATA_DIR, trainingData, labels);



    Ptr<ml::NormalBayesClassifier> classifier = ml::NormalBayesClassifier::create();

    if (trainingData.data == NULL || labels.data == NULL){
        cerr << "Mats are NULL!!" << endl;
    } else {
      classifier->train(trainingData,ml::ROW_SAMPLE, labels);
    }
//#warning Not yet tested
//    cout << "Processing evaluation data" << endl;
//    Mat evalData(0,dictSize,CV_32FC1);
//    Mat groundTruth(0,1,CV_32FC1);
//    extractBOWDescriptor(EVAL_DATA_DIR, evalData, groundTruth);

    return 0;
}
```

## EDIT

As requested here is the error.

- Through terminal: `Floating point exception: 8`
- XCode 6: `Thread 1:EXC_ARITHMETIC (code=EXC_i386_DIV, subcode=0x0)`

Answer (score 0):

Please try to change

```
labels.push_back(label);
```

to

```
labels.push_back((int)label);
```

I had the same problem with SVM training and realized that class labels must be ints.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Just to share how I solved the same issue on my os x project.

Apparently, it does seem that the matrix containing the labels is the problem in my project too. For some strange reason, creating the matrix in any other way, or typecasting to int the values pushed into the matrix did not work for me.

The problem was only solved by following the way OpenCV 3.0.0 SVM tutorial's sample code initialised its matrix of labels. [OpenCV SVM tutorial](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d1/d73/tutorial_introduction_to_svm.html#gsc.tab=0)

Which goes by:

```
int labels[4] = {1, -1, -1, -1};
Mat labelsMat(4, 1, CV_32SC1, labels);
```

After I changed my matrix of labels to be initialised as such from an array of integer labels, the error went away.