# OpenCV Python Unsupported response type

Tags: python, opencv

I am currently writing a Bag Of Words analyser using OpenCV and Python. I have been able to extract the info from the images, learn but the problem is the training part. As a baseline, I am using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13664437/a-matrix-with-zero-rows-and-1000-columns) and translating it into Python, but I get to the learn part and when it should train the classifier it fails saying that it has an unsupported response type (I assume labels is not in the correct format). I have tried a bit of everything but I cannot get it to work. Any ideas?

```
import cv2
import os
import numpy as np


dictSize = 1000
retries = 1
flags = cv2.KMEANS_PP_CENTERS
tc = (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, 10, 0.001)


matcher = cv2.DescriptorMatcher_create("FlannBased")
extractor = cv2.DescriptorExtractor_create("SURF")
detector = cv2.FeatureDetector_create("SURF")

bowTrainer = cv2.BOWKMeansTrainer(dictSize,tc,retries,flags)
bowDE = cv2.BOWImgDescriptorExtractor(extractor,matcher)


def extractTrainingVocabulary(path):
    global bowTrainer
    global extractor
    lst=os.listdir(path)

    for i in range(0,len(lst)):
        if lst[i][0] != ".":
            fullPath = path + lst[i]
            print "Processing Image " + fullPath
            img = cv2.imread(fullPath)
            if not (len(img) == 0):
                keypoints = detector.detect(img)

                if (len(keypoints) == 0):
                    print "Warning! Could not find any keypoints in image " + fullPath
                else:
                    # Returns 2 vars. The underscore is used to discard the first one
                    _,features = extractor.compute(img,keypoints)


                    bowTrainer.add(features)
            else:
                print "Could not read image " + fullPath

def extractBOWDescriptor(path, descriptors, labels):
    global bowTrainer
    global extractor
    lst=os.listdir(path)

    for i in range(0,len(lst)):
        if lst[i][0] != ".":
            fullPath = path + lst[i]
            print "Processing Image " + fullPath
            img = cv2.imread(fullPath)
            if not (len(img) == 0):
                keypoints = detector.detect(img)

                if (len(keypoints) == 0):
                    print "Warning! Could not find any keypoints in image " + fullPath
                else:

                    bowDescriptor = bowDE.compute(img,keypoints)
                    # descriptors.append(bowDescriptor)
                    #np.vstack((descriptors,bowDescriptor))

                    descriptors = np.vstack((descriptors,bowDescriptor))


                    #labels.append(lst[i][:-4])
                    labels = np.vstack((labels,float(lst[i][:-4])))



            else:
                print "Could not read image " + fullPath

    return labels, descriptors
def main():
    global bowDE

    # LEARN
    print "Creating Dict..."
    extractTrainingVocabulary("./testImages/")
    descriptors = bowTrainer.getDescriptors()

    print "Clustering " + str(len(descriptors)) + " features. This might take a while..."
    dictionary = bowTrainer.cluster()
    print "Done clustering"


    # EXTRACT
    size1 = 0,dictSize
    trainingData = np.zeros(size1,dtype=np.float32)
    size2 = 0,1
    labels = np.zeros(size2,dtype=np.float32)



    bowDE.setVocabulary(dictionary)
    labels,trainingData = extractBOWDescriptor("./evalImages/",trainingData,labels)


    print(trainingData)
    print(labels)

    print "Training classifier"

    size3 = len(trainingData),len(trainingData[0])
    responseData = np.zeros(size3,dtype=np.float32)






    classifier = cv2.NormalBayesClassifier()
    classifier.train(trainingData,labels)


main()
```

## EDIT

as per @berak's suggestion, I changed the following:

`labels = np.vstack((labels,float(lst[i][:-4])))` -> `labels = np.vstack((labels,int(lst[i][:-4])))`

`labels = np.zeros(size2,dtype=np.float32)` -> `labels = np.zeros(size2,dtype=np.int32)`

Unfortunately still fails. Now I get the following:

`error: (-5) There is only a single class in function cvPreprocessCategoricalResponses`

Comment: since you want a classification (not regression), you need integer responses(labels), not float

Comment: could you be a bit more specific?

Comment: your `labels` must be integer

Comment: Check my edit, still fails

Comment: your labels don't make any sense, imho. you need several classes (at least 2)